# Get delta of parent form field widget

Tags: 8, forms

I've got some form input fields in a paragraph whose visibility need to be dynamically toggled by the value of a another field. This can be done with the states API and the HOOK_field_widget_WIDGETTYPE_form_alter hook.

My problem is that the paragraph is nested inside another paragraph, and I don't know how to get the delta of the parent widget, in order to build my selector name for the states API.

My node has a paragraph `field_pagebuilder`, which contains another paragraph `field_row`. All toggleable/dependant fields are inside the same sub-paragraph. This is the code I've got so far:

```
function wt_pricetable_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'pricetable_frontend') {

    $deltaSelf = $context['delta'];
    //////////////////////////////
    $deltaParent = 0; // FIXME: how to I get this?
    //////////////////////////////
    $element['subform']['field_pt_showroom']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'single_room'],
        ],
      ],
      'required' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'single_room'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
    $element['subform']['field_pt_hiderooms']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'multi_room'],
        ],
      ],
      'required' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'multi_room'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
    $element['subform']['field_bem_modifier']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'multi_room'],
        ],
      ],
      'required' => [
        [
          'select[name="field_pagebuilder['.$deltaParent.'][subform][field_row]['.$deltaSelf.'][subform][field_pt_tablemode]"' => ['value' => 'multi_room'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

My problem is the `$deltaParent` - how can I retrive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in `$context['form']['#parents']`. This is an array that contains the keys of the parent widget. In my case it looked like

```
[ 0 => 'field_pagebuilder',
  1 => ___PARENT_INDEX___,
  2 => 'subform',
]
```

which allowed me to generate my CSS selector for the states API:

`$deltaParent = $context['form']['#parents'][1];`